# check permission in custom workflow function

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

I would like to use `isPermitted()` method in my custom workflow function but it seems not working as expected, my logs send me back true even for the record where my user doesn't have access.

If I put log in the method `isPermitted()` `(vtigercrm/include/utils/UserInfoUtil.php)` the current_user is 1 while i'm logged with another user (207).

But if the `isPermitted` method is call, by example, in the class `Vtiger_Save_Actions`, the current user is the right one.

Can you tell me why if I call `isPermitted` in my custom function the current user is 1 and if `isPermitted` is call by `Vtiger_Save_Actions` current user is the right one (207) ?

Must I replace `$current_user->id by $_SESSION["authenticated_user_id"]` ? In this case it's OK

My custom worflow function is the following:

```
function getExpenseType(){
    global $adb,$log, $current_user;

    $log->debug("ALTAIR getExpenseType OK");

    $sql = $adb->pquery( "SELECT expensetypeid 
    FROM vtiger_expensetype
    INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_expensetype.expensetypeid 
    WHERE vtiger_crmentity.deleted = 0" );

    $rows = $adb->num_rows($sql);

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++ ) {
        $recordId = $adb->query_result($sql, $i, 'expensetypeid');
        $moduleName = getSalesEntityType($recordId);

        if ( Users_Privileges_Model::isPermitted($moduleName, 'DetailView', $recordId) ) {
            $value[] = $recordId;
        }
    }

    $record = implode(',',$value);
    $log->debug("LOG: ExpenseType: ".json_encode($record));
}
```

if I add log trace in isPermitted() method, the current_user is 1 while 207 (the currently logged in user) :

```
function isPermitted($module,$actionname,$record_id='')
{
    global $log;
    $log->debug("Entering isPermitted(".$module.",".$actionname.",".$record_id.") method ...");

    global $adb;
    global $current_user;
    global $seclog;
    require('user_privileges/user_privileges_'.$current_user->id.'.php');
    require('user_privileges/sharing_privileges_'.$current_user->id.'.php');

    $log->debug("LOG: Current user: ".$current_user->id);

    $permission = "no";
    if(($module == 'Users' || $module == 'Home' || $module == 'uploads') && $_REQUEST['parenttab'] != 'Settings')
    {
        //These modules dont have security right now
        $permission = "yes";
        $log->debug("Exiting isPermitted method ...");
        return $permission;

    }
```

Jérémy

Comment: Show more code please. There is too few information here for understanding the problem.

Comment: code added
Thanks

Comment: Your `isPermitted` is getting user object from the global variable `$current_user`. The code you've shown never describe how this variable is set.

Comment: Are you sure vtiger would provide a valid `$current_user` at the code section you use `isPermitted`?

Comment: Yes $current_user id valid.

Comment: As you said, the user id was not correct (expected 207 but got 1). Something must have been wrong with the `$current_user` in your use. Did you try to log all contents in `$current_user`?

Comment: Id is not correct if I call isPermitted not in a vtiger class. I'm going to check how $current_user is set

Comment: OK I had my answer, It seems that the $current_user variable is not set by the way in custom workflow, I saw that in an old post on vtiger forum:

not always,
in custom workflow method (for ex: accounts)
global $current_user;
returns admin user (with $current_user->id == 1)
because of vtworkflowutils->adminuser(); method